# How to get rid of funcall in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

According to this document: http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/functions.html

```
(defun adder (n)
  (lambda (x) (+ x n)))
(funcall (adder 12) 1)
```

I have to use funcall to call (adder 12), And it is very ignoring to write funcall over and over, is there any way to write code like it in scheme:

```
((adder 12) 1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. There is none.

You can also see it as a feature: it makes calls of function objects explicit and improves understandability of source code.

Comment: This is the best possible answer. A corollary: if you want to write scheme, write scheme.

Answer (score 1):

However, you could use something like this (not sure why would you, but the number of characters typed would be the same as it is in Scheme):

```
(set-macro-character
 #\[
 #'(lambda (stream char)
     (declare (ignore char))
     (set-syntax-from-char #\] #\;)
     (let ((forms (read-delimited-list #\] stream t)))
       (set-syntax-from-char #\] #\x)
       (append '(funcall) forms))))

(defun adder (n)
  #'(lambda (x) (+ x n)))

(format t "sum: ~s~&" [(adder 12) #x128]) ;; 308
```

This *may* give you some problems if you will encounter a variable name with brackets in it. Sure, using it is up to you, consider yourself warned.